# Xcode code comments code-snippet shortcut not working

Tags: ios, xcode, code-snippets

In Xcode 7b6 or 7 in general, my code snippet completion shortcut is not working for my documentation comment snippets. Worked previously. I tried deleting the snippet and recreating it. I tried restarting computer & Xcode. Autocomplete still does not populate desired snippet for `HeaderDoc`. I also tried creating different completion code variables. This is what I use for autocomplete which worked previously with all other Xcode versions:

`HeaderDoc`

And this is what the code snippet should display:

```
/**
 *@description <#description#>
 *@param <#param description#>
 *@param <#param description#>
 *@return <#return description#>
 *@code

 *@endcode 
 *@see <#website url#>
 *@discussion <#discussion#>
 *
*/
```

Comment: Check the scoping settings on the snippet and try changing the trigger word to something all lower case with an underscore in between header_doc

Comment: @uchuugaka completion scope is set to Class implementation never had an issue with it, i have tried changing the trigger, i even tried case sensitive words prior to posting, i'll see if underscore helps out

Comment: hmmm underscore didn't work initially @uchuugaka I deleted the snippet > deleted the Xcode beta > reinstalled > recreated the snippet with a trigger word similar to your recommendation. all is well now, thanks for the guidance. I don't know what fixed it, but I didn't want to take risks on naming it what I previously named it, clearly that was conflicting with something else. I guess an answer is appropriate if you wish to do so

Comment: sometimes with the beta I've had it need relaunch to work again. :)